# python-docx will not autocomplete on IDEs

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-docx

I recently started using python-docx to work with Word documents and for some reason, it doesn't show up in the autocomplete. I tried VSCode and PyCharm. Other added libraries autocomplete fine in both.

I found [this](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/378) issue, but it is closed and the response is to ask in SO. I would appreciate any help.

Also, if this doesn't work out, is there any other python library to work with docx?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason, but python-docx code completion works in pycharm console and IDLE. In IDLE, you have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to obtain the pop up menu though. Hope this helps. :)

IDLE:
[image]

Pycharm console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code for import python-docx:

```
import docx.document as #any thig that you are comfortable whit it
```

import in this way and autocomplete will works.

**I apologize for my weak language**